# React Redux handling response after axios resubmit original request

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, interceptor, redux-saga

I have a small booking program to practice ReactJS + Redux + ReduxSaga + Axios + Axios Interceptor + JWT authentication

Here is the code in the component BookingDialog after the submit button click

bookingDialog.js

```
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let payload = {
            selectedDate: selectedDate,
            carId : carDetail.id,
            userId : user.login.id, //or pass by jwt accesstoken
            remarks: remarks
        }
        console.log(payload);
        dispatch(createBooking(payload));
    }
```

And there is saga watcher which take latest of action createBooking to function handleCreateBooking

bookingSaga.js

```
export function* handleCreateBooking(action) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(createBooking, action.payload);
        const { data } = response;
        console.log("handleCreateBooking");
        console.log(response);
        if (data && data.result && data.result > 0){
            console.log("booked successfully");
            yield put(setMessageBarOpen({type: "success", content: "booked successfully"}));
            yield put(setCreateBookingOpen(false));
        }
        else{
            console.log("booked failed");
            //yield put(setMessageBarOpen({type: "error", content: "booked failed"}));
            //yield put(setCreateBookingOpen(false));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

bookingRequest.js

```
const createBooking = (payload) => {
    return postUrl(apiURL.createBooking.url, payload).then((res) => {
            return res
        });
}
```

The program works as expected. Success message shown and booking dialog closed after submission.

If the jwt is expired, the program will retrieve the access token by refresh token and resubmit the original request with the new access token.

**The problem is that, after the original request is sent and booking is created successfully, the follow up actions (setMessageBarOpen & setCreateBookingOpen) are not performed** as the posting of original request is not under the function handleCreateBooking in bookingSaga.js

axiosInstance.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import apiURL from "requests/apiURL";

const ax = axios.create();

ax.interceptors.request.use(
    request => {
        const accessToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')) && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).accessToken;
        if (accessToken) {
          let auth = false;
          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(apiURL)) {
            if (request.url.includes(value.url)) {
              auth = value.auth;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (auth) {
            request.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
          }
        }
        return request;
      },
      error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
);

const sendRefreshToken = (refreshToken) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("refreshToken");
      postUrl(apiURL.token.url, { token: refreshToken })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          if (res.data) {
            console.log(res.data);
            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({accessToken: res.data.accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken}));
            resolve(res);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
    })
  }

ax.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    error => {
        console.log("axios.interceptors.response");
        console.log(error);
        const status = error.response ? error.response.status : null;
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        let isRefreshing = false;
  
         if (status === 403) {
          if (!isRefreshing) {
            const refreshToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')) && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).refreshToken;
            console.log("403, refreshToken:");
            console.log(refreshToken);
            isRefreshing = true;
            sendRefreshToken(refreshToken)
              .then(({ status }) => {
                console.log(status);
                if (status === 200 || status === 204) {
                    isRefreshing = false;
                    console.log("start resendRequest");
                    console.log(originalRequest);
                    return ax(originalRequest);
                }
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
              });
          }
        }       
        return error;
    }
);

export const getUrl = async (url, opt) => {
    const response = await ax.get(url, opt);
    return response;
}

export const postUrl = async (url, data, opt) => {
    const axios_res = await ax.post(url, data, opt);
    return axios_res;
}
```

How should I handle the response from the resubmitted original request?
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to configure the redux dev tools and check whether the actions are dispatched instead of tracing it with console logs .

Comment: when checking in dev tools , Is the actions getting dispatched ?

Comment: Thanks Shyam. I have checked with redux dev tool. In normal flow(access token not expired), the dispatch action sequence is booking/createBooking --> messageBar/setMessageBarOpen --> booking/setCreateBookingOpen. In resubmission flow(access token expired), only booking/createBooking is dispatched

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the console ?

Comment: The only error in console is the 403 Forbidden due the expired access token. Just observed that the 403 response is returned in handleCreateBooking(bookingSaga.js) after the postUrl(apiURL.token.url, { token: refreshToken }) in sendRefreshToken(axiosInstance.js), which makes me confused...

Comment: Looks like when you make the api , the token is expired and since you have used try catch in your saga function . It now reaches the catch block as the API fails . what you need to do is you should retry the failed request with once you get the new access token .

Comment: I resolve the issue finally. I haven't called the sendRefreshToken(refreshToken) with await, so the 403 error is returned to handleCreateBooking immdiately without waiting for the resubmission of original request. Sorry for wasting your time :P